# Showing a content of a UIView loaded from a xib in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

**Current Setup**

I have a subclass of a `UIView` that loads a content from a xib file -  call it a `XibOwnerClass`. Also, among other classes, there is a class called `Triangle` which helps me to create triangles with or without a border, with different stroke or fill color etc. That class is designable in storyboard and some of its properties are defined as `IBInspectable`.

Currently, in my `xib` file, I use this triangle view and setup its inspectable properties through `IB`. And that is really cool and convenient... So if I look into `xib`, I will actually see the triangle view among other views.

So, lets go further. In order to use this `XibOwnerClass`, I drag the `UIView` element to the storyboard, and change its custom class to `XibOwnerClass`, so I get my designable properties specific for `XibOwnerClass`. So, I can setup all things in `IB` and when I run the app, everything works.

**The problem**

Even if this works, I wonder if there is a way, to have multiple views (of class `XibOwnerClass`) dragged on a storyboard, and to be able to configure all of them individually trough Interface Builder?

Currently when I drag the `UIView` and change its custom class to `XibOwnerClass` I see nothing. I mean, the view is there, and it has its standard properties + inspectable properties. But I can't see triangles defined in `xib` in this new view. Is there a way to do this?

I am aware that `xib` is reused in my case (and it is meant to be used like that), so if I change something in a `xib`, all views that load from it will be affected. But is there a way multiple views to load from the same `xib`, but when loaded, to see them & setup them individually?

Here is how I load from `xib`:

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){

        UIView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXib" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

        if (myView){

            myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
            [self addSubview:myView];

            //Initialize other stuff

            [self commonInit];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then in `awakeFromNib:` I use the values of inspectable properties...

EDIT:

Also I don't have `initWithFrame:` implemented, but I thought that it is not needed if load from nib (because it is not executed). But maybe this is needed while design time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it. It turned out that I shouldn't use Main Bundle but rather bundle for that class, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35397975/3402095).

So here is the code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

@Mohammadalijf's answer in general *is* correct. It is just not a direct solution for my issue. But later on, when I fixed bundle thing, I used prepareForInterfaceBuilder like he said, and initialized things there so everything was available at design time.

Some useful stuff related to all this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202160/3402095) as well.

Answer (score 2):

can't really say what's wrong when you don't share class codes. but i guess you didnt use prepareForInterfaceBuilder. in your XibOwnerClass override prepareForInterfaceBuilder and call setups for view inside it for example change background colour or so.

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        //prepare setups or things to show in storyboard

}
```

Comment: I will update my question with some code. Also, this method is never executed in my case (I have  put a breakpoint). And please note that I see inspectable properties in IB for my XibOwnerClass. I just don't see any content from an actual xib.

Comment: Ah, this method is called only at design time, not at build time. Anyways, I see no differences. Currently, I don't see nothing. It is just like I have added ordinary view + inspectable properties (in Attributes Inspector). No content can be seen.

Comment: It worked now, I made an answer as well. Thanks for your answer though. You got my upvote, because that was of course a missing part to solve my issue.