# Xcode unresponsive because of IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch when exiting Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

For quite some time now, the Xcode project for our iOS App has been making problems when viewing the "Main" storyboard.

Whenever we enter the "Main" storyboard, it builds the views like it should and lets us work on the layout. However when we then try to exit that storyboard and try to display any other file in Xcode (no matter the file type), Xcode becomes unresponsive. Looking into the "Activity Monitor" app on our Mac, it displays the following process:

[image: Activity Monitor displaying "IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch" at 100% CPU Usage]

Manually stopping that process makes Xcode responsive again. Now the following is displayed in the Issue Navigator:

[image: Issue Navigator displaying multiple "Failed to render and update auto layout status (...) The agent crashed" errors]

The ViewControllers it mentions are completely white, but the project becomes usable again and building and running our app results in the correct interface being displayed.

I've looked into similar questions but can't seem to find someone with this exact problem. [This IB Designable Error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374330/ibdesignable-error-ib-designables-failed-to-update-auto-layout-status-interf) doesn't seem to apply, since our project stops responding upon exiting the storyboard and doesn't just automatically throw a non-blocking error.
[The accepted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374330/ibdesignable-error-ib-designables-failed-to-update-auto-layout-status-interf/35397975) also doesn't help us, since there are no actual crash logs left behind - the process doesn't crash, it hangs and needs to be manually stopped. There are no crash reports generated in the mentioned folder.

Our app currently has three storyboards, but this only happens with the "Main" storyboard, so the error might relate to a certain element in that file. We are using several IBDesignable Elements, however all of them import either none or both init statements, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265906/ibdesignable-crashing-agent).

Is there any way to look into what makes the IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch process use this much CPU and ultimately makes Xcode unresponsive?

Comment: I avoid using IBDesignables altogether because of bugs like this and I'd advise you to to the same.