# Displaying an SCNScene above a CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, scenekit

Thanks to the answer provided here -- [Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient) --
I am able to set a color gradient for the background of the homescreen of my app.

Prior to programming the color gradient using a CAGradientLayer, the user would press a button on the homescreen, and my SCNScene would appear.

Now, with the gradient in place, I can't seem to get the SCNScene to appear. All I can see is the color gradient. I've tried constructing an SCNLayer "above" the CAGradientLayer, but XCode yells at me.

What gives? Shouldn't it be simple to display a CAGradientLayer in the background with an SCNScene in front of it? I'm relatively new to this - thanks in advance.

Comment: if Xcode gives you an error, it would be useful to see it.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the object - SCNLayer @mnuages

Comment: `SCNLayer` only exists on OS X, is it an iOS project? If so you can use `SCNView` which is always layer-backed and can be placed on top of any other view.

Comment: Ah wow thanks I missed that in the docs somehow. Yep it's an iOS project. I'll fool around with just using SCNView. Wish I could accept your comment somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNLayer` only exists on OS X, is it an iOS project? If so you can use `SCNView` which is always layer-backed and can be placed on top of any other view.