# UISearchController add CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I would like to add gradient in `UISearchController` not work.

[image]

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;



[self.searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 79)];


CAGradientLayer * grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
grad.frame =  self.searchController.searchBar.bounds;

grad.colors = @[(id)UIColorFromRGB(0x8daf00).CGColor,
                    (id)UIColorFromRGB(0xd1af03).CGColor];


[ self.searchController.searchBar.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];
```

Comment: where you add this code in viewdidload or else, if it is in viewdidload change this to viewdidappear

Comment: refer this link ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient. @Luis Teodoro Junior

Comment: the gradient is correct and working, the problem is that the UISearchController not recognize the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, add this field and run

```
[self.searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set backgroundimage to searchbar.

```
  gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.1];
  [self.searchController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromLayer:gradient]];


- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, 0);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```