# Add a grey/white gradient to a UILabel Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, gradient

I am new to gradients on labels with Objective-C in an xcode project.  I currently have a plain white UILabel acting as my top toolbar on my application, but am trying to add a grey gradient to the label to make it look more like a toolbar.  The desired gradient is supposed to look something like this: [image: Ideal Gradient]

All I need is the Objective-C code added to a UILabel to make a gradient that is similar to the one shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23074591/2069114) you should be able to customize your UILabel as you want.