# Dynamic backgroundColor UIImageView does not update iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uibackgroundcolor

When I move the view cursor of first UIImageView, I get output the color of the point rgb using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. With this color I have to create a gradient in the second uiview that starts from the left of the starting color and comes to the right to the white. I noticed that after calculating the first rgb the color of the backgroundColor of second UIView is corrected but after moving the cursor of the first UIView and getting changes in rgb the color but the backgroundColor of second uiview remains unchanged.

[image]

```
  @objc func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        let color = self.imageView.getPixelColorAt(point: gestureRecognizer.view!.center)
       // color is correct

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
             self.gradientview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
             self.gradientview.gradientBackground(from: color, to:   UIColor.white, direction: GradientDirection.leftToRight)
       // color is correct only first time, after remains unchanged
        }, completion:nil)

    }
 }
```

In extensions

I create gradient starting from this example
[Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient)

```
  enum GradientDirection {
     case leftToRight
     case rightToLeft
    case topToBottom
    case bottomToTop
 }

 extension UIView {
     func gradientBackground(from color1: UIColor, to color2: UIColor, direction: GradientDirection) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]

    switch direction {
    case .leftToRight:
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    case .rightToLeft:
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    case .bottomToTop:
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    default:
        break
    }

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set to nil all sublayer

```
 self.gradientview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 self.gradientview.layer.sublayers = nil

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

            self.gradientview.gradientBackground(from: color, to: UIColor.white, direction: GradientDirection.leftToRight)


   }, completion:nil)
```