# table cells with same gradient in objective C

Tags: objective-c, calayer

How can I apply gradient on multiple table cells so it will appear as one view using Gradient layer. I don't want as follows instead both cells should look as one view with this layer. Is it possible? I show following cells in multi level table hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: you could either use a background image with the gradient or you could create a view with color gradient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:-

Set your Cell Color as

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Then:-

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableview.frame];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
self.tableview.backgroundView=view;
```